# Razor select list (dropdownlistfor) setting default selected value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdownlistfor

I have a select list which I set up in my view model first like this:

```
  public string selectedLocation { get; set; }

        public SelectList location = new SelectList(new[]
        { 
            new SelectListItem { Text = "United Kingdom", Value = "GB" },
            new SelectListItem  {Text = "United States", Value = "US" , Selected = true },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "United Kingdom", Value = "GB" },
            new SelectListItem  { Text = "Australia", Value = "AU" },
            new SelectListItem  { Text = "China", Value = "CN" },
            new SelectListItem  { Text = "France", Value = "FR" },
            new SelectListItem  { Text = "Germany", Value = "DE" },
            new SelectListItem  { Text = "Italy", Value = "IT" },
            new SelectListItem  { Text = "Canada", Value = "CA" }
        }, "Value", "Text");
```

As you can see I have set the default value for the US - select to true, thus this value should be selected in drop-down by some logic?

And this is where i show it in HTML:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedLocation, Model.location, new { @class = "select2", @style = "width:95%;border-left:2px solid #eee" })
```

But the selected item in dropdown is always the first one, no matter what I set in viewmodel...

What am I doing wrong here ? :/

Comment: What is the value in `model.selectedLocation`?

Comment: @rene when posting the form or when rendering the view ?

Comment: rendering the view. I assume that is where your question is about, right?

Comment: @rene yes, correct.. None actually.. I just create the viewmodel object and pass it into the view... I set the property now to some of the values, n it looks good =D

Comment: Glad you solved it ...

Comment: @rene your hint was good enough to find the cause.. :) You wanna post the answer so that I can accept it ?

Comment: Meh, this is so trivial, post a self answer if you like. Or I could find a dupe ...but I'm out of close votes ...

Comment: @rene haha okay , posted :D

Comment: @rene i can delete the question if u want ?

Comment: It is good like this. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

So the source of the issue was that I had to set the model.selectedLocation value before passing the model into the view and rendering it like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
   var model = new myClassViewModel();
   model.selectedLocation = "IT"; // as rene stated
   return View(model);
}
```

Thanks to @rene